# Doctrine2 add 'LIKE' to addOrderBy

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, query-builder

The query I am trying to make using the Doctrine2 query builder is:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl t0_ ORDER BY t0_.column1 LIKE '%value%' DESC, t0_.id DESC
```

What I have at the moment:

```
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->add('select', 'p')
        ->add('from', 'S2\Entity\Tbl p')
        ->addOrderBy('p.column1 LIKE "%value%"', 'DESC')
        ->addOrderBy('p.id', 'desc');
```

This results in an exception `Error: Expected end of string, got 'LIKE'`.

How do I add this `like` to my `addOrderBy`?

#### Edit

As an alternative, I have also tried:

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->add('select', 'p')
    ->add('select', 'LOCATE("value", p.column1) as HIDDEN field_search')
    ->add('from', 'S2\Entity\Tbl p')
    ->addOrderBy('field_search', 'DESC')
    ->addOrderBy('p.id', 'desc');
```

but that keeps throwing the exception about not knowing what `locate` is.

The reason I am wanting to do this is to show the rows with `value` above the rest of the rows.

For example, my table looks like:

```
id | column1
1  | some text
2  | some content
3  | contains value
4  | Could contain value
5  | some more text
6  | lots of text
```

The output I am after is:

```
id | column1
4  | Could contain value
3  | contains value
6  | lots of text
5  | some more text
2  | some content
1  | some text
```

so the id is sorted descending, with the rows containing `value` appearing at the top of the result set.

Comment: Why are you adding that to the ORDER BY clause? It should go in the WHERE clause!

Comment: I don't want to filter the results, I just want the rows with the string "value" to be at the TOP of the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use next Query for filter your data by relevance:

```
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $result = $qb->select("p")
        ->from('S2\Entity\Tbl', 'p')
        ->addSelect("(CASE
                   WHEN p.column1 like 'Text %' THEN 0
                   WHEN p.column1 like 'Text%' THEN 1
                   WHEN p.column1 like '%Text' THEN 2
                   ELSE 3 END) AS HIDDEN ORD "
        )
        ->addOrderBy('ORD', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: That will filter my results to show only those that contain the value. I want to show all, but list those with value at the top of the results.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I've updated query for new requirements.